# Modify the values in a dictionary and return the key and the modified value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I created a dictionary with pandas and I'm trying to get only the value

```
a                   b
hello_friend        HELLO<by>
hi_friend           HI<byby>
good_friend         GOOD<bybyby>
```

I would like to get the list of values, apply multiple methods only on it and at the end return the key and the modified values

```
def open_pandas():
    df = pandas.read_csv('table.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
    dico = df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(list).to_dict()

    return dico

def methods_values(dico)

    removes = b.str.replace(r'<.*>', '')
    b_lower = removes.astype(str).str.lower()
    b_list = dico.to_dict('b')
    #here, I'm going to apply a clustering on the values

    return dico_with_modified_values
```

I need the two functions (but my second function is not working) and my desired output:

```
{"hello_friend": ['hello'],"hi_friend": ['hi'], "good_friend": ['good']}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need first processes column `b` of `DataFrame` and then convert it to dictionary of lists:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('table.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
df['b'] = df['b'].str.replace(r'<.*>', '').str.lower()
dico = df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(list).to_dict()
print (dico)

{'good_friend': ['good'], 'hello_friend': ['hello'], 'hi_friend': ['hi']}
```